# Is it possible to search a Sharepoint documents library and exclude results from any directories named "Archive" and subdirectories of "Archive"?

Tags: sharepoint

Is there search query syntax that can be entered at the top of the SharePoint Microsoft 365 site in the search box to search for any files and folders that meet a given word or words but not include any results from directories named "Archive" or any sub-directories under an "Archive" directory?

A sample directory structure

```
My Docs
--Notes
----Archive
------2022_10_05
--Forms
----Archive
My Pictures
--Archive
My Misc
--Archive
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the subject of the post
[SP365 - Exclude specific folder from search results](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245470/sp365-exclude-specific-folder-from-search-results).

I quote below the
[answer by Chad](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/245511/4345) :

> You can use advanced search to add a "Does not contain" rule to
> exclude results based on a specific url path. This adds a querystring
> parameter that "negates" that path from existing on a specific
> property, such as:
>
> ```
> http://url/search/Pages/results.aspx?k=-SPSiteUrl%3A"mylibrary/health
> ```
>
> & safety/drafts"
>
> Notice the negative sign in front of SPSiteUrl.
>
> This can be applied "by default" using the Search webpart
> configuration. Edit the page where your search results are displayed
> and edit the Search Results webpart. Then use the "Change Query"
> option to configure it as needed similar to above.

Comment: I don't understand in that specific answer why "k=" is involved.  In Microsoft 365 Sharepoint I'm seeing it write a "q=" when using the Search box.

Comment: I'm not using SharePoint at the moment, but one can add parameters after the `?` separated by `&`. I'm guessing that you could have `...results.aspx?q=...&k=-...`.